# How to move from schema stitching to federated subgraphs after upgrade of many libraries?

Tags: migration, apollo-server, apollo-federation, apollo-gateway, graphql-compose

I need to move from schema stiching to federated subgraphs using graphql-compose, graphq-compose-mongoose, apollo-subgraph apollo-server after an upgrade of all the libraries

I have a gateway using apollo gateway that create a supergraphSDl using IntrospectAndCompose.

My gateway was using schema stiching before and I want to move to federated subgraphs.

So far my subgraph is exposed and the gateway can fetch it but there is nothing setup to link my subgraphs together without the schema stiching.

I've followed this link on how to [migrate from schema stitching to my subgraph](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/migrating-from-stitching/)

Do anyone knows how to add the @key on my Types and also how to change the types returned by the schemaComposer to have the Links to the external subgraph?

I'll then need a bit of help to create and expose the new federated resolvers as for now everything that I return is from the schemaComposer.